# display message using cookie. js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with message , what I was trying to do is display the div message once in 24 hour(in a webpage) or anything that will be functional. Below is the code which I tried but I am unsuccessful. I don't need local storage this has to be done by cookie , please help. any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
//this is just for the test

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   if ($.cookie('#novbar') == null || $.cookie('#novbar') == ""){
    $.cookie("#novbar", 1, {expires: 1, path : '/'});
   }
   <script>
```

```html
//this is just for the test

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<div  id ="novbar" style="position:absolute; font-size:20px; left:25px; top:0px; display:none"> We will be decomissioning application please contact us 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check to see if the cookie doesn't exist and then execute your code if it does, also you might need to pass a string as a value for the cookie that's what the documentation states...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (!$.cookie('#novbar')) {
            $.cookie("#novbar", 'string', {expires: 1, path : '/'});
        }
```